# Which novel has the earliest appearance of the consumption of monsters as food?

Tags: history-of, magical-creatures

I came across people talking about adventurers eating the monsters that they hunt, so I was wondering:

**"What is the earliest appearance of adventurers eating weird food made from the remains of the monsters, in fiction?"**

By monsters, I'm not talking about wolves/dire wolves, or giant rats, or anything else that's made of flesh, viscera and bones, or plant matter..., I'm talking about things that aren't basically the same as a common food creature, but more, like slimes...

However, if an answer has 'this adventurer ate slimes', with the adventurer's culture having blancmanges, or some other kind of jelly, as a normal food, then eating slimes is not far enough out of the adventurers' normal experiences of eating things for me to accept it.

Comment: Gelatinous cubes are great at parties

Comment: That said, I've seen plenty of games where dragon parts are food. Or do dragons count as animals for this purpose?

Comment: @cde - I guess dragons != animals, unless you can think of a way to say dragons + wyvern + giant apples != monsters, but slimes + beholders + golems = monsters? ... Oh! Anything that isn't made of meat, and bones, is a monster?

Comment: People eat ashes sometimes.  Charcoal is sold as an antacid.  Moses is said to have made the Israelites drink water mixed with the ashes of the Golden Calf they had begun to worship while he was receiving the Ten Commandments.

Comment: Also, the last sentence of your question seems to suggest that you would accept an answer that named a novel in which someone eats ice.

Comment: @WadCheber - Hmm... Okay... perhaps remove golems... Accepting an answer where people eat ice... Hmm... What I might accept is a novel that has a dead ice golem, and people eat its remains, perhaps as part of a slushie? Hmm... Nah... Editing Again... See ya tomorrow!

Comment: How about alien blancmanges?

Comment: Would the phoenix count as a "monster"?

Comment: I know Bruenor from the Drizzt books, would tend to eat some of the things they called, I can recall him trying to eat trolls and other things from the forgotten realms. But the restrictions on the word monster make it seem like your looking for a different answer, although I wouldn't be surprised to find out he tried to eat a stone golem or something at one point.

Comment: @slebetman - It would be interesting, but I think I wouldn't accept it, 'cause Phoenix is basically a 'bird on fire'... While something like a 'beholder' can't be accurately termed as 'giant squid with laser eyes'... ... Do you get what I'm saying? I sorta don't....

Comment: @JoeL - ... If the adventurer's culture has blancmanges as a normal food, then eating slimes is not far enough out of the normal experience of eating things for me to accept it... ... Gotta alter the question again...

Comment: Asking *if* a trope exists is strictly off-topic. Asking which is the first instance is on-topic.

Comment: @DVK - Yes. It seems to fit. Monster Remains that are consumed and their form is not of a food common to the consuming culture.

Comment: @DVK - True... It's not like anyone else has any answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it's the earliest, but *Dune* seems to qualify.

- **Monster**: Sandworms of Dune
- **Food made from the remains of the monsters**: Spice Melange